# Match_all with filter on percolator not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch v1.1.1

I am getting an unexpected result from a percolator. I have broken it down to it's simplest parts and am still getting weird results.

Firstly I create a new index with mapping:

```
PUT /test1
{
   "mappings": {
      "product": {
         "properties": {
            "subject": {
               "type": "nested",
               "properties": {
                  "code": {
                     "type": "string"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then I create two objects for testing:

```
PUT /test1/product/12345
{
    "subject": {
        "code": "FA"
    }
}

PUT /test1/product/12346
{
    "subject": {
        "code": "BA"
    }
}
```

Then I create a query that I would expect to match on the second record only:

```
GET /test1/product/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": []
         },
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must_not": [
                  {
                     "query": {
                        "nested": {
                           "path": "subject",
                           "query": {
                              "prefix": {
                                 "subject.code": "fa"
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

So far everything is working as expected. The query returns the second record, the first one being excluded by the filter.

I then use the same query to create a percolator:

```
PUT /test1/.percolator/TEST
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": []
         },
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must_not": [
                  {
                     "query": {
                        "nested": {
                           "path": "subject",
                           "query": {
                              "prefix": {
                                 "subject.code": "fa"
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And test against both records:

```
GET /test1/product/12345/_percolate

GET /test1/product/12346/_percolate
```

They both return the same result:

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "total": 1,
   "matches": [
      {
         "_index": "test1",
         "_id": "TEST"
      }
   ]
}
```

I have tested this without a nested object and it operates as I would expect. At first I thought perhaps the match_all was doing something strange to the percolator but when it wasn't a nested object it worked fine.

So my question is, am I missing something obvious? Is this expected behaviour and I have just missed it in the documentation, or is this a bug?

I understand I could easily create this query in a different way (and am open to some suggestions) however I am building them programatically so the bool structure seems the best option. I have also tried using a "not" filter with a nested "or" filter with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug. It is fixed in version 1.2.2.

More info: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/6540